# Error while including <ctype> on atom using c++11

Tags: c++, macos

I was trying to use isapha() on c++11 and hence had to include ctype> but when i try doing that it gives me the error:

```
fatal error: 'ctype' file not found #include <ctype>
```

Comment: 'en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype' reports that std::ctype is defined in header <locale>.  But I also find "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-45/include/linux/ctype.h" and other files like ctype.h and  /usr/include/c++/7/cctype.

Answer (score 1):

The correct filename is `cctype`, not `ctype`, since it comes from C's `ctype.h`, and all C libraries in C++ have the `c` prefix and no `.h` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

The available options are `<ctype.h>` and `<cctype>` (Note: two 'c's, not just one). The latter is generally preferred.